# What's the best way to count keywords in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string

What's the best and most efficient way to count keywords in JavaScript? Basically, I'd like to take a string and get the top N words or phrases that occur in the string, mainly for the use of suggesting tags. I'm looking more for conceptual hints or links to real-life examples than actual code, but I certainly wouldn't mind if you'd like to share code as well. If there are particular functions that would help, I'd also appreciate that.

Right now I think I'm at using the split() function to separate the string by spaces and then cleaning punctuation out with a regular expression. I'd also want it to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut, paste + execute demo:

```
var text = "Text to be examined to determine which n words are used the most";

// Find 'em!
var wordRegExp = /\w+(?:'\w{1,2})?/g;
var words = {};
var matches;
while ((matches = wordRegExp.exec(text)) != null)
{
    var word = matches[0].toLowerCase();
    if (typeof words[word] == "undefined")
    {
        words[word] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        words[word]++;
    }
}

// Sort 'em!
var wordList = [];
for (var word in words)
{
    if (words.hasOwnProperty(word))
    {
        wordList.push([word, words[word]]);
    }
}
wordList.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });

// Come back any time, straaanger!
var n = 10;
var message = ["The top " + n + " words are:"];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    message.push(wordList[i][0] + " - " + wordList[i][1] + " occurance" +
                 (wordList[i][1] == 1 ? "" : "s"));
}
alert(message.join("\n"));
```

Reusable function:

```
function getTopNWords(text, n)
{
    var wordRegExp = /\w+(?:'\w{1,2})?/g;
    var words = {};
    var matches;
    while ((matches = wordRegExp.exec(text)) != null)
    {
        var word = matches[0].toLowerCase();
        if (typeof words[word] == "undefined")
        {
            words[word] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            words[word]++;
        }
    }

    var wordList = [];
    for (var word in words)
    {
        if (words.hasOwnProperty(word))
        {
            wordList.push([word, words[word]]);
        }
    }
    wordList.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });

    var topWords = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        topWords.push(wordList[i][0]);
    }
    return topWords;
}
```

Comment: Damn, you must have a lot more free time on your hands than I do! Can I send you some work? ;) J/K Just giving you a hard time because you basically gave this guy full working code rather than just a few bits and pieces (like I did). Make the guy figure *something* out on his own!

Comment: It only took a few minutes. A couple of minutes longer than it should have, as I'm on "sit very quietly in the dark and listen for the child waking up in the next room" duty, so I keep mistyping :)

Comment: @insin Wow, thanks. Much more than I was expecting, but it will serve as a great reference point.
@Jason I'm writing a MooTools class with a few more options, so there's still a little more work to do. insin definitely helped, though.

Answer (score 4):

Once you have that array of words cleaned up, and let's say you call it `wordArray`:

```
var keywordRegistry = {};

for(var i = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
   if(keywordRegistry.hasOwnProperty(wordArray[i]) == false) {
      keywordRegistry[wordArray[i]] = 0;
   }
   keywordRegistry[wordArray[i]] = keywordRegistry[wordArray[i]] + 1;
}

// now keywordRegistry will have, as properties, all of the 
// words in your word array with their respective counts 

// this will alert (choose something better than alert) all words and their counts
for(var keyword in keywordRegistry) {
  alert("The keyword '" + keyword + "' occurred " + keywordRegistry[keyword] + " times");
}
```

That should give you the basics of doing this part of the work.

Comment: Sure thing - I would've taken the time to post a full solution, but I have work to do and need to get paid! :) Besides, this is the most interesting part to me anyway (which really isn't that interesting) - the rest is easy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split you string on words and count the resulting words, then sort on the counts.

Answer (score 1):

This builds upon a previous answer by *insin* by only having one loop:

```
function top_words(text, n) {
    // Split text on non word characters
    var words = text.toLowerCase().split(/\W+/)
    var positions = new Array()
    var word_counts = new Array()
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        var word = words[i]
        if (!word) {
            continue
        }

        if (typeof positions[word] == 'undefined') {
            positions[word] = word_counts.length
            word_counts.push([word, 1])
        } else {
            word_counts[positions[word]][1]++
        }
    }
    // Put most frequent words at the beginning.
    word_counts.sort(function (a, b) {return b[1] - a[1]})
    // Return the first n items
    return word_counts.slice(0, n)
}

// Let's see if it works.
var text = "Words in here are repeated. Are repeated, repeated!"
alert(top_words(text, 3))
```

The result of the example is: `[['repeated',3], ['are',2], ['words', 1]]`

Answer (score -1):

I would do exactly what you have mentioned above to isolate each word. I would then probably add each word as the index of an array with the number of occurrences as the value.

For example:

```
var a = new Array;
a[word] = a[word]?a[word]+1:1;
```

Now you know how many unique words there are (a.length) and how many occurrences of each word existed (a[word]).

Comment: This won't work - you're really using the Array as an Object there, not as an Array. Adding properties to an Array like that will only update the reported length of the array if the property is numeric.